# Why can't my Terraria server running in docker find it's world file?

Tags: server, files, docker

I am using [beardedio's docker-compose file for Terraria servers](https://hub.docker.com/r/beardedio/terraria) :

```
version: '3'

services:
  terraria:
    image: beardedio/terraria:vanilla-latest
    ports:
      - '7777:7777'
    restart: unless-stopped
    environment:
      - world=myworld.wld
    volumes:
      - $HOME/terraria/config:/config
    tty: true
    stdin_open: true
```

I have the docker-compose.yml file saved in /home/terraria/config, which is also where the worldfile is stored. After checking logs, it seems the container is constantly restarting due to not finding the world file:

```
~$ docker logs --tail 50 --follow --timestamps config_terraria_1
2022-06-18T09:37:59.015754844Z World file does not exist! Quitting...
2022-06-18T09:37:59.648848860Z World file does not exist! Quitting...
2022-06-18T09:38:00.312203861Z World file does not exist! Quitting...
2022-06-18T09:38:01.167585791Z World file does not exist! Quitting...
2022-06-18T09:38:02.388691358Z World file does not exist! Quitting...
2022-06-18T09:38:04.437094345Z World file does not exist! Quitting...
2022-06-18T09:38:08.084673575Z World file does not exist! Quitting...
2022-06-18T09:38:14.948840125Z World file does not exist! Quitting...
2022-06-18T09:38:28.196745171Z World file does not exist! Quitting...
2022-06-18T09:38:54.270838042Z World file does not exist! Quitting...
```

Does anyone know where I should be putting the file, or if the issue is more complicated?

Sorry if I'm not following correct etiquette or something, relatively new to both this forum and Ubuntu/Linux

Comment: Could you please include the output of `ls -la /home/terraria/config` to your question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a problem with the path for the volume mapping. Try to use absolute paths with no variables, i.e.:

```
volumes:
  - /home/terraria/config:/config
```

Please report if this fixes the issue?